# C# OledbCommand returning invalid data

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Fellas,

I got stuck up in a piece of code and it has been troubling me for quite some time now. I would really like your help on this one.

What I'm trying to do is to connect to an Microsoft Access database, create an SQL statement, create an OledbCommand, add the OledbParameters and try to execute the query. However, the query is returning incorrect data.

First off, here's my code:

```
string dbPath = "D:\\reports.mdb";

List<string> emails = new List<string>();
emails.Add("user1@e2k10.lcl");
emails.Add("aliasuser1@e2k10.lcl");

StringBuilder sbContactsLastComm = new StringBuilder();
sbContactsLastComm.Append("SELECT ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("MAX([meces_processed].[datetime]) ");

sbContactsLastComm.Append("FROM ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_processed], ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_users], ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_emailusers] ");

sbContactsLastComm.Append("WHERE ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_emailusers].[userid] = [meces_users].[id] ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("AND [meces_emailusers].[emailid] = [meces_processed].[uniqueguid] ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("AND [meces_users].[emailaddress] = ? ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("AND [meces_processed].[uniqueguid] IN ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("( ");

sbContactsLastComm.Append("SELECT DISTINCT ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_processed].[uniqueguid] ");

sbContactsLastComm.Append("FROM ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_emailusers], ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_users], ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_processed] ");

sbContactsLastComm.Append("WHERE ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("[meces_emailusers].[userid] = [meces_users].[id] ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("AND [meces_emailusers].[emailid] = [meces_processed].[uniqueguid] ");
sbContactsLastComm.Append("AND [meces_users].[emailaddress] IN ( ");

for (int i = 0; i < emails.Count; ++i)
    sbContactsLastComm.Append("?, ");

sbContactsLastComm.Remove(sbContactsLastComm.Length - 2, 2);
sbContactsLastComm.Append(" ) ) ");

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbPath))
{
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sbContactsLastComm.ToString(), conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("contact", "user@domain.com"));


    for (int i = 0; i < emails.Count; ++i)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("email" + i, emails[i]));

    foreach (OleDbParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
        Console.WriteLine(p.ParameterName + " = " + p.Value);

    object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    conn.Close();
}
```

Secondly, here's what I've tried:

I outputted the sql statement and it's correct. I outputted the OledbCommand parameters and they're correct too.

What I've also tried is I put the sql into Microsoft Access and replaced the ?s with the actual parameters and the statement executed successfully. Then I also tried hardcoding the paramters into the sql instead of through the use of OledbParameters and it worked fine as well.

I don't want to end up having the hardcode my sql statements as I would like to use OledbParameters for obvious reasons.

I've tried the exact same thing using SqlServer (and SqlConnection etc.) and this worked perfectly fine. Still no luck with Access though! The expected result should be a date and time, however, I'm receiving an empty result (DBNULL).

Any help / pointers would be really appreciated!!

Comment: Try to run very simple parameter-less query, if it works, then make one with parameters, etc. Until it will stop working, but then you will know why.

Comment: Thanks Sinatr for your reply. I've already tried that. Whenever I have 1 or 2 parameters, it works fine. However, when I add the third parameter, its not working. Also, it doesn't matter which parameter I add as OledbParameter because, as long as I have 2 parameters, it works fine. Any more ideas please?

Comment: Don't know if its a false parameter interpretation or not, but how about changing to   emails[i].ToString() )).   I dont know if the OleDbParameter is looking at it as an object vs char string or what.

Comment: Try to name parameters starting from `@` (as in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) example) and specify their `OleDbType`.

Comment: Thanks DRapp for your reply. I tried your suggestion but still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Sinatr for your reply. I tried naming the parameters with the @  as in the example. I tried this: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@p" + i, OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = emails[i].ToString();`